# Uncaught RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and for training, I want to create a basic Todo app. For the first step, I want to create a component called AddTodo that renders an input field and a button and every time I enter something in the input field and press the button, I want to pass the value of the input field to another component called TodoList and append it to the list.

The problem is when I launch the app, the AddTodo component renders successfully but when I enter something and press the button, the app stops responding for 2 seconds and after that, I get this: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` and nothing happens.

My app source code: Main.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TodoList from 'TodoList';
import AddTodo from 'AddTodo';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setNewTodo = this.setNewTodo.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            newTodo: ''
        };
    }
    setNewTodo(todo) {
        this.setState({
            newTodo: todo
        });
    }
    render() {
        var {newTodo} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <TodoList addToList={newTodo} />
                <AddTodo setTodo={this.setNewTodo}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Main;
```

AddTodo.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class AddTodo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleNewTodo = this.handleNewTodo.bind(this);
    }
    handleNewTodo() {
        var todo = this.refs.todo.value;
        this.refs.todo.value = '';
        if (todo) {
            this.props.setTodo(todo);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" ref="todo" />
                <button onClick={this.handleNewTodo}>Add to Todo List</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
AddTodo.propTypes = {
    setTodo: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
export default AddTodo;
```

TodoList.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderItems = this.renderItems.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            todos: []
        };
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        var newTodo = this.props.addToList;
        var todos = this.state.todos;
        todos = todos.concat(newTodo);
        this.setState({
            todos: todos
        });
    }
    renderItems() {
        var todos = this.state.todos;
        todos.map((item) => {
            <h4>{item}</h4>
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderItems()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time `componentDidUpdate` is called (which happens after first change in its props/state, which in your case happens after adding first todo) it adds `this.props.addToList` to `this.state.todo` and updates state. Updating state will run `componentDidUpdate` again and it adds the value of `this.props.addToList` to 'this.state.todo` again and it goes infinitely.

You can fix it with some dirty hacks but your approach is a bad approach overall. Right thing to do is to keep todos in parent component (`Main`), append the new todo to it in `setNewTodo` (you may probably rename it to `addTodo`) and pass the todos list from `Main` state to `TodoList`: `<TodoList todos={this.state.todos}/>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of react is whenever you call setState function, react component get updated which causes the function componentDidUpdate to be called again when the component is updated.

Now problem here is you are calling setState function inside componentDidUpdate which causes the component to update again and this chain goes on forever. And every time componentDidUpdate is called it concat a value to the todo. So a time come when the memory gets full and it throws an error. You should not call setState function inside functions like componentWillUpdate,componentDidUpdate etc.

One solution can be to use componentWillReceiveProps instead of componentDidUpdate function like this:

```
      componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
            var newTodo = nextProps.addToList;
            this.setState(prevState => ({
               todos: prevState.todos.concat(newTodo)
            }));
      }
```